# Add where clause to every query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a situation where i have updated all database tables to include a new field called "siteid". Therefore i want to execute a where clause in every query generated by codeigniter.

Is there any way of doing this without manually adding the where clause in every model?
Here is an example

```
$this->db->select('username');    
$this->db->where('userid');
$this->db->get('user');
$query->result_array();
```

I want to add a new where clause to every query so that it works like this

```
$this->db->select('username');    
$this->db->where('userid');
$this->db->where('siteid');
$this->db->get('user');
$query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create MY_Model.php inside core/ folder and make all your models extend MY_Model.

Then add this line:

```
$this->db->where('siteid');
```

into the constructor of MY_Model.php.

More info about extending core classes can be found [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it without doing it manually.

You could maybe just use search and replace current method with associative array method of where search. [Documentation link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Search for

```
$this->db->where('userid');
```

and replace with

```
$this->db->where(['userid' => $userid, 'siteid' => $siteid]);
```